# Maven test result in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven

I run maven goal test with IntelliJ and I get back a :

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project, there are test failures.
```

Where I can see what test failed?

Comment: You have test failures you should the output which test is failing...or even better start the tests from your ide and see the results...

Comment: How I start test from ide and choosing a maven profile?

Comment: Why do you need a profile for unit tests. Apart from that I see running the build in Maven (let IDEA build your code)...

Comment: Because a Maven profile has associated the environment variables needed for the test, so the gola is to start the test with specific environment variables

Comment: Then your unit tests are wrong. Furthermore you could give them on surefire configuration without a profile. If they are needed to be different then they are even more wrong and your unit tests are integration tests. And the question is what those tests are really testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's ok in latest IntelliJ versions to see the failed tests in the intellij run panel see the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]

To see even better details on your successful / failed steps click on the eye icon on the left of the panel and shoose "show successful steps".

I hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot see any results in the run panel. Only the "Failed to execute goal"

Comment: even after you clicked on your project where I described on the first screenshot?

Comment: have you tried to re-import your maven project and update dependencies? if you already did that can you try to update your intellij too? Can you share a sample project to reproduce the problem? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the build folder there might be a surefire report file

Answer (score 0):

Check under {project.dir}/target/surefire-reports